# nvcc: command not found

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I installed cuda sdk 5.0 to /opt and even compiled all examples, but I can't execute nvcc. Here is some console output:
[image]
I'm using linux mint 13.

Comment: what happens if you type `/opt/bin/nvcc --version`  If that works, then your .bash_profile is not updating your path for some reason.  Maybe you need to log out and log in again to get the updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATED

I did multiple changes to .bash_profile, nvcc is now found. Here is .bash_profile:

```
export LPATH=$LPATH:/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/opt/bin:/opt/lib64:/opt/lib
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/opt/lib64:/opt/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/opt/lib64:/opt/lib
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/bin:/opt/lib64:/opt/lib
```

Comment: That's puzzling since you did `ls /opt/bin` and it showed the nvcc executable, and other cuda binaries.